# Cancel Handler on a KeyUP Event? VB.NET

Tags: regex, windows, vb.net, keyup

There a way to use e.Cancel () on a keyup event?

I'm trying to validate a textbox with a Regex and I need to cancel the event if it no meets the Regex expression, or delete the key pressed to meet so that the expression

For Example:

```
Dim rex As Regex = New Regex("^[0-9]{0,9}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$")
Private Sub prices_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.KeyUp,

        Dim TxtB As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

        If (rex.IsMatch(TxtB.Text) = False ) Then
            e.cancel = true
        End If

    End Sub
```

**ERROR:** 'cancel' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
If (rex.IsMatch(TxtB.Text) = False) Then
  e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End If
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress.aspx):

> You can assign true to this property in an event handler such as KeyDown in order to prevent user input.
>
> Setting SuppressKeyPress to true also sets Handled to true.

It's unclear what you are trying to cancel though, since you are reading the TextBox.Text value.  `KeyDown` is usually the preferred event to intercept the keystroke.

If you are trying to validate the entire string, the `Validating` event might be more appropriate.  With TextBox controls, you will always have the danger of someone pasting clipboard text into the control, which could bypass key events.